# dificuldade pra listar os dados no datatable do angular 4

Tags: html5, angular

Como título diz, não consigo carregar os registros do banco no dataTable do PrimeNG.

Não aparece mensagens de erro no console do VisualCode, não aparece mensagens de erro no console do navegador de internet, não aparece notificações de erro no próprio código.

Eu acho que o problema deva ser no HTML, preciso de ajuda para saber como resolver isso, esse aqui é meu código.

Código do serviço;

```
import { Noticia } from './../core/model';

import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Injectable()
export class NoticiaService {

  noticiasUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/noticias';


  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  pesquisar(): Observable <Noticia[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.noticiasUrl}`)
      .map(response => response.json().content);

  }


}
```

Código do componente;

```
noticias = [];

  constructor(private noticiaService: NoticiaService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.pesquisa();
  }


  pesquisa() {
      this.noticiaService.pesquisar()
      .subscribe(noticias => this.noticias = this.noticias);
  }
```

Código HTML;

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="ui-g">



    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-fluid">
      <label>Descrição</label>
      <input pInputText type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <label style="display: block">Vencimento</label>
      <input pInputText type="text" style="width: 95px">

      <label>até</label>
      <input pInputText type="text" style="width: 95px">
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <button pButton type="submit" label="Pesquisar"></button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-12">

      <p-dataTable [value]="noticias" [paginator]="true" [rows]="5"
      [responsive]="true">

   <p-column field="dataNoticia" header="Data da noticia" styleClass="col-data">
        <ng-template let-lanc="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          <span>{{ lanc.dataNoticia | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</span>
        </ng-template>
      </p-column>
      <p-column field="titulo" header="Titulo"></p-column>
       <p-column field="font" header="Fonte" styleClass="col-valor"></p-column>
          <p-column styleClass="col-acoes">
              <ng-template let-lanc="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                <button pButton icon="fa-angle-double-right"
                pTooltip="Visualize" tooltipPosition="top"
                ></button>
              </ng-template>
            </p-column>
      </p-dataTable>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Faz um teste coloca um *ngIf="noticias" no div em volta da p-dataTable

Comment: Como eu colocaria isso no Datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ngOnInit() {
     this.pesquisa();
  }

//O erro estava que tinha um this extra aqui
  pesquisa() {
      this.noticiaService.pesquisar()
      .subscribe(noticias => this.noticias = noticias);
  }
```

Comment: você está dizendo que o erro está nesse trecho de código, mas não consigo ver diferença com o meu código.

Comment: O seu esta .subscribe(noticias => this.noticias = this.noticias);

Comment: O segundo nao devia ter o this

Comment: hahaha, valeu, muito obrigado